# Getting "EOFError" when running Python code on Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, eoferror

I'm trying to run python code with the [atom-runner](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner) for atom, but it returns an EOF error.  I did what other answers to similar questions said to do, and put raw_input() instead of input(), but it still returns and EOF error.

Here is my code:

```
tempf = int(raw_input("What is the temperature in fahrenheit?  "))
tempc = (tempf - 32) * 5 / 9
print("The temperature in celsius is", tempc, "degrees.")
```

Here is the error:

```
What is the temperature in fahrenheit?  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents\Programming\Python\f2c.py", line 1, in <module>
    tempf = int(raw_input("What is the temperature in fahrenheit?  "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: STDIN is not supported: https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/98

Comment: Instead of `atom-runner`, you can use some terminal packages or `script`.

Comment: I don't use atom-runner, however, your code runs fine. If you use Python 2.X then use `raw_input` for input, for Python 3.X use `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing together the answers from the comments, as it stands [`atom-runner` does not support STDIN](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/98), the linked issue was responded to with:

> Thanks! If someone wanted to put together a pull request to support this it would probably be accepted (if it looked good and didn't break anything, that is).

*However*, as quite rightly pointed out you can probably acheive what you are looking for by using the [script package](https://atom.io/packages/script).

Comment: The Github link is dead. The Github repo was archived. :(